# Grub question mbr

Tags: grub2

Apparantly I have grub installed on the MBR of 2 drives, my question is 'how can I check this?' And 'how can I solve this?'

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 lte in dual boot with Windows 7, this all works fine.

Comment: If it is not broken, don't fix it .

Comment: Good philosophy 

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/61400/how-do-i-tell-if-grub-is-installed-on-a-device

Answer (score 1):

There is one very helpful shell script to examine the situation:

```
# be aware: unsupported (universe) package!
sudo apt-get install boot-info-script
sudo bootinfoscript
```

You COULD overwrite the MBR of the unused (non-primary in boot order) disk by erasing the first 100 bytes, but why?

My recommendation is, keep everything unchanged. e.g. i always booted grub from my non-linux disks mbr, but when that crashed, i still has the grub in my main HDD and could continue to use my PC.

Comment: Thanks, I will leave it as it is then. Everything runs perfect, took a while to figure it out. But eventually figured it out. Now it's time to learn how to use Ubuntu 